# Android : Text in ForeGround of a FrameLayout (contain a googleMap)

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-framelayout, foreground

**Hello everyone**

To start, sorry for my bad english

I first put you in position:

I'm using Java code for Android, in Eclipse.

My application needs to show a map (Google Maps V2) in a fragment to show the runner location. The map display is already achieved.

Here is my problem: I use a FrameLayout element, which contains my map and is therefore the whole page, however, my goal is to display over the map a text box centered at the bottom. I tried to use in the Foreground property option to set my text, but it does not work (application crash when arrived on the page of the map).

Here is my code fragment_carte:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mapFrameLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:foreground="@id/txtViewCoureur"
    tools:context=".CarteFragment" >
</FrameLayout>
```

*I can't post an image to show you what I want because it's my first post*

I tried many solutions on this forum before asking my question

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Enclose the map inside a RelativeLayout and the rest of the controls in a FrameLayout. Here is an example of one app I have:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/mapview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            class="MapFragment" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/mapsearchbox"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:alpha="0.8"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:hint="@string/map_search"
                android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="30dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black" >
            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/mapsearchbtn
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_close_clear_cancel" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have try your solution but it doesn't work :/ my code is behind